# How do I template a Javascript file with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to create an Ansible role to install and configure [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/) and I'm struggling with templating the `settings.j2` file.

```yaml
- name: Write the NodeRED settings file
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: templates/settings.js.j2
    dest: "{{ _nodered_user_info.home }}/.config/node-red/settings.js"
    mode: "0644"
    owner: "{{ _nodered_user_info.name }}"
    group: "{{ _nodered_user_info.name }}"
  become: true
```

[settings.js.j2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyTMA.png)

This always throws the error:

> The error was: . expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'

I assume that Jinja2 is having difficulties with the single curly braces in the JavaScript file.

The syntax highlighting is not highlighting the first `if` tag properly.

I tried to replace all `{`with `{{ '{' }}` and all `}` with `{{ '}' }}`, but this makes the file unreadable and breaks the syntax highlighting.

Comment: You should post the contents of the "settings.js.j2" here as text, not link to a screenshot of the code.

Comment: "_I assume that Jinja2 is having difficulties with the single curly braces in the JavaScript file._", right. that's the case. You'll need to [escape](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#escaping) either via `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` or your already proposed solution "_I tried to replace all ... but this makes the file unreadable and breaks the syntax highlighting._".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your template source file is supposed to contain a lot of characters conflicting with the default jinja2 delimiters, you can change those directly in the `template` module. So for example:

```yaml
- name: Template my js file
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: my.js.j2
    dest: path/to/dest.js
    block_start_string: '<@'
    block_end_string: '@>'
    comment_start_string: '<#'
    comment_end_string: '#>'
    variable_start_string: '<:'
    variable_end_string: ':>'
```

should let you process a template looking like the following. Of course change the above (and below) to whatever best suits your needs:

```
<# This is a jinja template with custom delimiters #>
{
  "toto": "<: my_variable :>",
  "titi": {
  <@ if some_titi_switch @>
    "some_key": "a static value"
  <@ else @>
    "other_key": "some other value"
  <@ endif @>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I assume that Jinja2 is having difficulties with the single curly braces in the JavaScript file."*

Right. that's the case. You'll need to [escape](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#escaping). Either via your already proposed solution

> *"I tried to replace all ... but this makes the file unreadable and breaks the syntax highlighting."*

or via `{% raw %`} and `{% endraw %}` resulting into an

**`settings.js.j2`**

```yaml
line 0
...
line 22
---
{% raw %}
module.exports = {
line 24
...
line 42
{% endraw %}
{% if nodered_credential_secret | default(false) %}
    credentialSecret: "{{ nodered_credential_secret }}",
{% else %}
    // credentialSecret: "a-secret-key",
{% endif %}
...
```